# Why doesn't my CSV look like what i need it to look like?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I use Beautiful Soup to grab specific tables from several pages which URL are in the `url.csv`

The code:

```
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data



list_url=parse_csv(open('url.csv','rU').read())
f = csv.writer(open("raw.csv", "w",encoding='utf8',newline=''))
# Write column headers as the first line


for i in range (0,len(list_url)):
    url=str(list_url[i][0]) ## read URL from an array coming from an Url-CSV
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
    restricted_webpage= soup.find( "div", {"id":"ingredients"} )
    readable_restricted=str(restricted_webpage)

    soup2=BeautifulSoup(readable_restricted,"html.parser")


    links = soup2.find_all('td')
    print(len(links))


    for link in links:
        i = link.find_next_sibling('td')
        if getattr(i, 'name', None):
            a, i = link.string, i.string
            f.writerow([a, i])
```

My CSV looks like:

```
"
                Cendres brutes (%)
        ","
                7.4
        " "
                Cellulose brute (%)
        ","
                1.6
        " "
                Fibres alimentaires (%)
        ","
                6.6
        " "
                Matière grasse (%)
        ","
                16.0
```

Whereas I'd like it to look like :

```
Cendres brutes(%);7.4
Cellulose brute (%);1.6
Fibres Alimentaires(%);6.6
Mati̬re grasse (%);16.0
```

I need it to look like that for two reasons : 
1. It looks great when I open such CSV in excel. 
2. I can use my CSV parser (the one define at the first line `parse_csv`) and work on the array generated from my CSV like if it was cell on excel. cell[x][y]. Which is very handful.

How can I achieve that? It is to say having the kind of CSV that I want ?

Comment: For the record, files are genderless.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: If your only issue is whitespace, have you considered using [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove it?

Comment: Whitespace and there is ";" or "," problem somewhere. I can't get it work. If i add .strip to .string to link and i in the a,i line it's written : Name,Quantity
<built-in method strip of NavigableString object at 0x105fbacf0>,<built-in method strip of NavigableString object at 0x105fbad68>
<built-in method strip of NavigableString object at 0x105fbade0>,<built-in method strip of NavigableString object at 0x105fbae58>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';')
```

Transform coma in semi-colon. Readable by excel-EU.